# Why does Quantum Electrodynamics Allow a Photon to Exist Temporarily as a Positron and an Electron?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles, pair-production

In this question...

[Why does a photon colliding with an atomic nucleus cause pair production?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56296/why-does-a-photon-colliding-with-an-atomic-nucleus-cause-pair-production)

...I asked why a photon colliding with a atomic nucleus can become an electron and a positron.  The answer that I thought was most illuminating explained that a photon spends some of its travel time as a particle-antiparticle pair of an electron and a positron. If it strikes the nucleus at the right time, this pair will be separated. It was explained that this is because 'Quantum Electrodynamics allows it'.

Why does Quantum Electrodynamics allow a photon to exist temporarily as an electron and a positron?

Comment: I think there's a misconception in the question - it gives the impression of a situation where a propagating photon somehow objectively oscillates between being a photon and being an electron positron pair. That's not an accurate picture of the process of photon propagation. In fact there *is* no picture of the propagation - all QFT gives you is the probability amplitude to go from A in one polarization state to B in another. This amplitude gets corrected by some suggestive pictures which show the photon splitting and recombining, but these pictures are just tools to aid the calculation.

Comment: John, maybe it will help clarify the question if you edit in some words about why you think QED shouldn't allow this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the photon energy $E$ is sufficient to produce a pair ($E>2mc^2$), then a pair can be produced in a collision. It is due to equivalence of mass and energy. The same energy can be "represented" differently - as photons, particles, etc. Kind of conversion of one form of energy into another.

Comment: I understand it's "allowed" but not where the rules come from that allow it... I'm missing something fundamental about why the photon would do this and not just stay a photon...

Comment: @John, this is simply the observed behavior of quantum mechanics. It even has a name: "the totalitarian rule" (totalitarian because everything that is not forbidden is compulsory...). There is a level at which physics explains why (in terms of more fundamental physics), but at it root physics is descriptive not prescriptive and simply says *"this is how things are observed to be"*.

Comment: @John: A photon can stay a photon too. There is no obligation to convert into a pair. They say there are different channels of scattering with different issues including staying a photon as one of possible issues.

Comment: Isn't it in fact that "everything that's not forbidden by symmetry does happen"? :)

Comment: @Lagerbaer: Yes, a collision may have many different channels (issues) of occurring.

Answer (score 5):

**It is all hidden in the QED Lagrangian:**

One can answer this question in a simple way in terms of the QED Lagrangian, at the electron-field interaction part:

$L=\bar\psi(\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu-m_e+eA_\mu\gamma^\mu)\psi$

This tells us that interactions of the form:

$e^++e^-\rightarrow\gamma$..................(1)

$\gamma\rightarrow e^++e^-$..................(2)

are allowed. This then means that since (1) and (2) are allowed at tree level, at higher order QED the interaction (at one loop level)

$\gamma\rightarrow e^++e^-\rightarrow\gamma$

is also allowed. This is because there is nothing in the fundamental QED Lagrangian, $L$, to tell us that this is not possible. Special relativity as represented by the above Lagrangian allows $E_\gamma=2m_ec^2$ as well as $2mc^2=E_\gamma.$ Quantum mechanics also allows, via the uncertainty principle, for the $e^++e^-$ pair to exist in virtual states, unless some sufficiently strong Coulomb field, or even uniform electric field, or strong gravitational field like just outside a balck hole's event horizon (Hawking radiation) separates them from each other.